# Rxjava, how to defer emission until a number of subscribers subscribe?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm making Android app, having a beginner's question:
Is there a way to defer the Observables emission until say, 2 subscribers subscribe? since I don't want the 2nd one to miss out on the data.
Thanks

Comment: "Don't want the second one to miss out" - how do you know there's going to be a second one and when?  Only solution would be to archive emissions and let subscribers indicate a wish to get past data within a period of time.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this use case is supported by using the `ConnectableObservable` type for deterministically multicasting.

There are two approaches to using it.

The first and easiest is to use the `publish` overload like this:

```
    Observable<Long> sourceToShare = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // multiple subscriptions deterministically subscribed to using publish()
    sourceToShare.publish(l -> {
        Observable<String> a = l.map(t -> "first subscriber " + t);
        Observable<String> b = l.buffer(4).map(t -> "second subscriber " + t);
        return Observable.merge(a, b);
    }).take(20).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or if you need to manually control when the source starts and stops after connecting all the subscribers you can use ConnectableObservable directly like this:

```
    Observable<Long> sourceToShare = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


    // multiple subscriptions deterministically subscribed to using ConnectableObservable
    ConnectableObservable<Long> published = sourceToShare.publish();

    Observable<String> a = published.map(t -> "first subscriber " + t);
    Observable<String> b = published.buffer(4).map(t -> "second subscriber " + t);
    Observable.merge(a, b).take(20).forEach(s -> System.out.println("published => " + s));

    // now that everything is wired up, connect the source
    published.connect();

    // since we are connecting asynchronously and need to 'connect' after subscribing
    // we have to manually give it time to execute
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here are links to the docs:

- http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#publish(rx.functions.Func1)
- http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/ConnectableObservable.html
- http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#connectable

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the creation of the source `Observable`, have a look at the [defer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#defer(rx.functions.Func0)) function.

If you don't, have a look at the [ReplaySubject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html).

This "emits to any observer all of the items that were emitted by the source Observable(s), regardless of when the observer subscribes."

What you could do is, chain the `ReplaySubject` to your source `Observable`, and then return the subject's `Observable` to your caller by calling the `asObservable()` method. Then, anyone who subscribes, will get all the items emitted by the source `Observable`

EG

```
ReplySubject replySubject = ReplySubject.create();
sourceObservable.subscribe(replySubject::onNext, replySubject::onError, replySubject::onCompleted);
return replySubject.asObservable();
```

If your source Observable is very busy, you might need to create a time or size bounded version. Have a look at the [JavaDoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/ReplaySubject.html)